# Spark java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/v2/FileDataSourceV2

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I currently am trying to spark-submit a fat jar to a local cluster, which I developed using Spark 2.4.6; Scala 2.11.12. Upon submitting to the cluster, I receive this error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/v2/FileDataSourceV2`

My spark submit command (run in cmd prompt):
`spark-submit --class main.app --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.6 my_app_name-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

Other details:

- Scala version: 2.11.12
- Spark 2.4.6
- When I submit using Spark 3.0.0 (i.e. pointing my SPARK_HOME to Spark 3.0.0 directory and submitting), it works fine, but when I submit using Spark 2.4.6 (i.e. pointing my SPARK_HOME to Spark 2.4.6 directory and submitting) I get that error
- I have to use 2.4.6 (this cannot be changed)

**My pom file**

```
[....headers and stuff]
<groupId>org.example</groupId>
<artifactId>my_app_name</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<properties>
    <scala.version>2.11.12</scala.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>scala-tools.org</id>
        <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>scala-tools.org</id>
        <name>Scala-Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
        <version>5.6.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>specs</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-avro -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-avro_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql-kafka-0-10 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-tools -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-tools</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-streams -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.databricks/spark-csv -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.databricks</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-csv_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-aws</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <!-- see http://davidb.github.com/scala-maven-plugin -->
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <recompileMode>incremental</recompileMode>   <!-- NOTE: incremental compilation although faster requires passing to MAVEN_OPTS="-XX:MaxPermSize=128m" -->
                <!-- addScalacArgs>-feature</addScalacArgs -->
                <args>
                    <arg>-Yresolve-term-conflict:object</arg>   <!-- required for package/object name conflict in Jenkins jar -->
                </args>
                <javacArgs>
                    <javacArg>-Xlint:unchecked</javacArg>
                    <javacArg>-Xlint:deprecation</javacArg>
                </javacArgs>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <archive>
                            <manifest>
                                <mainClass>
                                    ingest_package.object_ingest
                                </mainClass>
                            </manifest>
                        </archive>
                        <descriptorRefs>
                            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                        </descriptorRefs>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

[....footers and stuff]
```

**My Main App File**

```
package main

import java.nio.file.{Files, Paths}

import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.avro.to_avro
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{date_format, struct}

object app {

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .master("local[*]")
  .appName("parquet_ingest_engine")
  .getOrCreate()

Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
val accessKeyId = System.getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
val secretAccessKey = System.getenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")


val person_df = spark.read.format("org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat").load("s3_parquet_path_here")
val person_df_reformatted = person_df.withColumn("registration_dttm_string", date_format(person_df("registration_dttm"), "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm"))
val person_df_final = person_df_reformatted.select("registration_dttm_string", "id", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "gender", "ip_address", "cc", "country", "birthdate", "salary", "title", "comments")

person_df_final.printSchema()
person_df_final.show(5)

val person_avro_schema = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("input\\person_schema.avsc")))
print(person_avro_schema)

person_df_final.write.format("avro").mode("overwrite").option("avroSchema", person_avro_schema).save("output/person.avro")
print("\n" + "=====================successfully wrote avro to local path=====================" + "\n")


person_df_final.select(to_avro(struct("registration_dttm_string", "id", "first_name", "last_name", "email", "gender", "ip_address", "cc", "country", "birthdate", "salary", "title", "comments")) as "value")
  .write
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
  .option("topic", "spark_topic_test")
  .save()

print("\n" + "========================Successfully wrote to avro consumer on localhost kafka consumer========================" + "\n"+ "\n")


  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you have problems with dependencies:

- you don't need `com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11` - CSV support is in the Spark itself for a long time
- you don't need Kafka dependencies except `org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.6`
- `spark-sql` and `spark-core` need to be declared with `<scope>provided</scope>` like [here](https://github.com/alexott/cassandra-dse-playground/blob/master/spark-oss/pom.xml#L32)
- it's better to use the same version of Spark dependencies as you're using for submission

Second, the problem could be from the incorrect Scala version (for example, you didn't do `mvn clean` when you changed it) - if you said that code works with Spark 3.0 then it should be compiled with Scala 2.12, while 2.4.6 works only with 2.11

I strongly recommend to get rid of unnecessary dependencies, use provided, do `mvn clean`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same error. And solved it by using the jar with same scala version and spark version. I see the jar version you are using (org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.6 ) is consistent with your spark, maybe you can try to change the version to a close one (e.g. org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.0 etc).

My spark is "version 2.4.4 using Scala version 2.11.12", when I read an avro file using the following jar(spark-avro_2.12), I got the exactly same error.
spark-shell --packages org.apache.spark:spark-avro_2.12:3.1.2

It was fixed after changing to "spark-shell --packages com.databricks:spark-avro_2.11:2.4.0".